# Suppress messages returned while running an SQL Job through batch file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using MS SQL Server 2012. I have an SQL job that needs to be run through a batch file. I have been able to do it (*quite easy as it is*).

Now, I want to suppress the message "**Job 'name_of_job' started successfully**" that appears in the command window. 
Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/53a63818-102d-425f-9e5d-3f36c443da56/suppressing-text-messages?forum=transactsql

Comment: Awesome! That does the trick. Thanks @Ivan Starostin. :)